# How to check that the document has no pages

Tags: itext

I am trying to use iTextSharp to convert some HTML mail from Outlook into PDF. Some mail gives problem to the `HTMLWorker`, generating exceptions.

In case this happens, I want to catch the exception and abandon the PDF creation. But I can not. What do I have to do to check and properly close the opened `Document`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly before calling `Close()` you can check the `PageNumber` property of your `Document` to see if there are any pages.

```
if (doc.PageNumber == 0) {
    //Do something here
}
doc.Close();
```

Also, the `HTMLWorker` class isn't being [actively developed anymore](http://www.lowagie.com/xmlworker). Instead, almost all new HTML parsing code is being done in a separate library called [`XMLWorker`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/). See @kuujinbo's [sample code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8576560/231316).

Comment: I just tried XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml() and it is too strict! Throws exceptions on missing closing tags etc. =( I am converting HTML that I have no control over...

Comment: doc.PageNumber returns 0 for a document with one page as well.. Doesn't seem to be a good way to decide whether something was added at all.

Answer (score -1):

Start with a new page and add your paragraphs:

```
Document document = new Document();

document.Open();

foreach (var item in List)
{
   document.NewPage();
   AddParagraph(item, document);
}

document.Close();
```

Comment: What if List is empty? The code will break on Close()

>>> System.IO.IOException: 'The document has no pages.'